# React Router 4 sitemap generation

Tags: reactjs, react-router, sitemap

I have a highly dynamic website for which I would like to generate a sitemap.xml. The idea would be to have the newly created dynamic records automatically added to the sitemap file along with a "last update on" date. I checked the current packages and it seems that react-router-sitemap is only compatible with react router v2. Is my only option to code myself a logic to generate the sitemap?

Thanks.